User secrets getting loaded at runtime but not at design time
I'm using IHost to create a service provider in a console app. I have set up user secrets that get loaded when running the project. However when I use the Package Manager Console with commands like Add-Migration user secrets don't get loaded.
public static async Task Main()
{
    IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
        .ConfigureServices((context, serviceCollection) =>
        {
            serviceCollection
                .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();
        })
        .Build();

    // Other code
}

public class ApplicationDbContext(IConfiguration configuration) : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<TestRequest> TestRequests { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        // This foreach loop doesn't log anything stored in user secrets at design-time while it does at runtime
        foreach (var item in configuration.AsEnumerable())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        string connStr = configuration.GetConnectionString("MySql") ??
            throw new NullReferenceException("MySQL conncetion string was null"); // Throws at design time

        optionsBuilder
            .UseMySql(connStr, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connStr));
    }
}

My user secrets ID is set in the .csproj file.
secrets.json
{
    "ConnectionStrings:MySql": "Server=localhost;Database=db;Uid=root;Pwd=mypwd;"
}


Could you also post how your secrets.json looks like?

Sure I updated the question
